# Why has Libreoffice stopped being visible in Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, libreoffice

In the past few days, Libreoffice has stopped playing nicely with Unity. When I have any of its components running, the icons in the taskbar don't have arrows next to them, and Alt-Tab doesn't show or allow access to any Libreoffice windows that I have open (but I can click them to bring them to the front).

This behaviour has changed just recently, and as far as I'm aware, nothing has changed on my system for the past few weeks other than installing recommended updates as normal.

Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 3):

Libreoffice hasn't played well with Unity for a while now. At times things are fine, then suddenly everything will break. Different problems occur to different people, but they all involve Libreoffice's integration with the launcher and alt-tab.

See this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1026426

You could hit alt-f2 and type `unity --replace` next time you have a problem, but if that works it's at best a temporary fix. Uninstalling/reinstalling libreoffice and/or `lo-menubar` are sometimes suggested as fixes to these problems, but, again, those are only temporary fixes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, unity --replace gets it back. Even if it's only temporary that's useful to me. Let's hope 12.10 fixes it properly!

Comment: No problem, hope it gets fixed soon too! Feel free to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Just a heads up for people having this issue: I tried the `unity --replace` command and it completely killed Unity. I had to Alt+PrtScr+REISUB to restart the system. All these constant constant constant little Unity annoyances are quickly driving me to other distros...